# Change a natural key to surrogate key

Tags: sql-server, migration

I have two tables, one witch primary key is a natural one and another who reference the first one (so referencing the natural key). Now I have to do some change over that part of my system and to start with I want to replace the natural key with a surrogate key (witch will simplify thing along the way).

I have most of my migration script written but I can't figure out how to populate the new reference column.

Let me illustrate what I mean with an exemple.

```
naturalKeyedTable
(
    newPk UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
    myOldPk VARCHAR(10)
    --other unimportant columns
)

referenceTable
(
    newFK UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
    oldFK VARCHAR(10)
)
```

I have populated the newPk column with the following SQL

```
UPDATE naturalKeyedTable
SET newPk = NEWID()
```

Now I need to also populate the newFK column. I can't quite figure out the required sql to do so.

I have tought something along the line of

```
UPDATE referenceTable
SET newFK = SELECT TOP 1 newPk FROM naturalKeyedTable WHERE oldFK = myOldPk
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something more like this.

```
update rt
set newFK = newPK
from referenceTable rt
join naturalKeyedTable nkt on nkt.myOldPk = rt.oldFK
```

Do be careful here. Your new primary key is a guid. I hope you have another column you can use as your clustered key. GUID columns as the clustered index will hit 99% fragmentation with as few as a few thousand rows and unless you defragment this index regularly your performance will be horrible.

Comment: Thank you for the query +1, I didn't knew about the index fragmentation. Could you provide me with a link or a reference on the subject so I can have a look at it.

Comment: The guid vs int primary key is a long running debate that can easily turn into a religious war. Remember that a guid is 4 times the storage space of an int. That alone is often enough to not use guids. I am not saying they don't have their place but they are not my choice for a go to surrogate key. It is painless to setup a table with a guid as the clustered index, then insert 1,000 and check out the fragmentation. Then increase to 10k rows and be prepared for defragmentation.

Comment: Ok thank you for that information. The fact i'm using guid helps a lot on the coding side of this but I will keep in mind the fragmentation thing. Also the fact is that it is a relatively low usage database so It shouldn't be that bad. This has been in use for the last 6 month and the biggest table has only 40k row

Comment: Ease on the coding side is a very common usage for choosing a guid as the PK. Take a look at the fragmentation of your clustered index on your 40k row table. Unless you are currently defragmenting it regularly, the fragmentation will be right around 99.xxx%. For my work I generally prefer to use an identity. To ease the pressure for development you can use OUTPUT to retrieve the identity values inserted. Not saying one is better than the other, just stating how I do it. I have been requested to write an article about guid key fragmentation, I guess I need to get it done. :D

Comment: I think the guid aren't really a problem in my case since I just check about index density and it aign't that bad check it out
- Extents Scanned..............................: 94
- Extent Switches..............................: 100
- Avg. Pages per Extent........................: 7.7
- Scan Density [Best Count:Actual Count].......: 90.10% [91:101]
- Logical Scan Fragmentation ..................: 0.83%
- Extent Scan Fragmentation ...................: 22.34%
- Avg. Bytes Free per Page.....................: 617.3
- Avg. Page Density (full).....................: 92.37%

Comment: What query did you run to check your indexes?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60014/discussion-between-im-a-noob-and-sean-lange).